# Standard Unit Conversion Tables

Tags: math, units-of-measurement

I've been tasked with looking into some issues regarding errors with unit conversions (Meters to Feet for example). Is there a definitive source for standard conversion numbers? I would like the conversion factors to be the highest precision possible.

I know there are a number of sites out there that offer a plethora of conversions, but what I am looking for is a standard, either official or defacto to use as a baseline.

A table with 32 and 64 bit numbers would be perfect.

Comment: if you can use java http://jscience.org/ may be of use.

Comment: Exactly what kind of units you looking for? The standard length and volumes? Do you need stuff like energy, frequency etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [unit definition file](http://fossies.org/linux/misc/units-2.01.tar.gz%3aa/units-2.01/definitions.units) of [GNU Units](http://www.gnu.org/software/units/units.html) lists a large number of sources:

> Most units data was drawn from
>
> 1. NIST Special Publication 811, Guide for the
>      Use of the International System of Units (SI).
>      Barry N. Taylor. 1995
> 2. CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics 70th edition
> 3. Oxford English Dictionary
> 4. Websters New Universal Unabridged Dictionary
> 5. Units of Measure by Stephen Dresner
> 6. A Dictionary of English Weights and Measures by Ronald Zupko
> 7. British Weights and Measures by Ronald Zupko
> 8. Realm of Measure by Isaac Asimov
> 9. United States standards of weights and measures, their
>      creation and creators by Arthur H. Frazier.
> 10. French weights and measures before the Revolution: a
>       dictionary of provincial and local units by Ronald Zupko
> 11. Weights and Measures: their ancient origins and their
>       development in Great Britain up to AD 1855 by FG Skinner
> 12. The World of Measurements by H. Arthur Klein
> 13. For Good Measure by William Johnstone
> 14. NTC's Encyclopedia of International Weights and Measures
>       by William Johnstone
> 15. Sizes by John Lord
> 16. Sizesaurus by Stephen Strauss
> 17. CODATA Recommended Values of Physical Constants available at
>       http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Constants/index.html
> 18. How Many?  A Dictionary of Units of Measurement.  Available at
>       http://www.unc.edu/~rowlett/units/index.html
> 19. Numericana.  http://www.numericana.com
> 20. UK history of measurement
>       http://www.ukmetrication.com/history.htm
> 21. NIST Handbook 44, Specifications, Tolerances, and
>        Other Technical Requirements for Weighing and Measuring
>        Devices. 2011
> 22. NIST Special Publication 447, Weights and Measures Standards
>        of the the United States: a brief history. Lewis V. Judson.
>        1963; rev. 1976

For many units, the file contains the official definition, so it will be as precise as it gets. The comments often explain where that definition came from.